# Missing configuration keys in MapReduce RunningJob interface

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a requirement where I programmatically need to access some configuration values I have have previously set on a MapReduce Job. The way that I set the configuration object

```
 final Configuration conf = new Configuration();
 conf.set("x", y));
 ......
 final Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, getJobName());
```

I am able to access to access these values from the mapper code. However I use the JobClient to get an instance of RunningJob and I try to retrieve these values from
the configuration object returned by the getConfiguration() method. I do not see the values that I set.

Could I be doing something wrong?